# How will McAfee LiveSafe react to an unknown flash drive?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, anti-virus

As of late, I've been using a Windows 10 laptop that is on loan to me from a friend of my dad's. Actually, if I'm going to split hairs about it, the laptop's technically on loan to me from my dad, but it's on loan to *him* from his friend. According to Dad, his friend doesn't have a problem with me using the computer, and I double-checked with him to make sure his friend would be okay with plugging a USB drive into it. However, the antivirus program installed on the computer, McAfee LiveSafe, is one that I'm not at all familiar with. Can anyone tell me how this software will react to a USB drive that's never been plugged into the computer before? If it's relevant, the USB drive is a 128GB SanDisk Cruzer Glide.

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by how it will *react*. Are you concerned it will react in a specific way?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I just don't want any of the files on my USB drive to be affected. Basically, I want to know what kind of popup(s)/message(s) I can expect to see, what the program could potentially do to/do with the drive, etc.

Comment: Asking what McAfee might do is too broad a question given the fact we don't know what's on that drive.